# Serverless FrameworkがサポートするNode.jsのバージョンの範囲について

Tags: node.js, serverless-framework

Serverless Frameworkの特定のバージョン（例えば3.35.xや3.38.xなど）がサポートしているNode.jsの下限と上限（例えば12.22.x～16.x.xなど）について調べているのですが、記載を見つけることができません。
どこかで纏まって説明されている箇所があれば、教えていただけないでしょうか。

Comment: 一応の確認ですが、これは「ツールとしてのServerless Framework自体のコマンド実行等に必要とするNode.js」と「Serverless Frameworkが各種IaaSにFunctions類をデプロイする実行環境のNode.js」のどちらを意識していますか？もし前者であれば、[GitHub上で公開されているpackage.json](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/blob/v3.38.0/package.json)内のengines > nodeを参照すると良いかもしれません。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。情報が不足しており申し訳ございません。
以下リンクの質問の例で言いますと、「Error: Serverless Framework v3 does not support Node.js v12.13.0.」の部分が本件の意図となります。
https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/12169

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コメントを踏まえて、「CLIとしてのServerless Frameworkがどのバージョンで動作するか」についてですと、**v3.35～直近リリース分ではNode.js v14.0以降のみがサポートの対象**となっているようです。

上限については記載が無いですが、この場合は何かしらのトラブルがIssueとして上がっていないのであれば「基本的に上位バージョンでも動作する=上限なし」と捉えていいかと思います。

### ソースコード実態として

[`package.json`上では`"engines.node" = ">=12.0"`と記述されています。](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/blob/main/package.json#L244)
このセクションはパッケージのインストールなどにおける制限事項として働く項目となっているのですが、メンテナンスがされていない可能性があるようです。（結果として[Issue化](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/12169)されている模様）

なお、このメッセージ自体はリポジトリ内にある[`serverless/bin/serverless.js`内](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/blob/main/bin/serverless.js)で実装されています。コード内の`minimumSupportedVersionMajor`,`minimumSupportedVersionMinor`がサポート判定に使用されています。
mainブランチ並びにv3.38.0の場合はそれぞれ`14`,`0`が設定されているため、v14.0以上でないと動作しないように実装されています。
※GitHubのWeb画面上でタグやブランチを切り替えていくと「このバージョンはどのバージョン以降で動作するか」を確認することができます。なお、v3.34.0ではNode.js v12.13以上がサポート対象になっていたことがわかります。

### まとまった情報はあるか？

おそらくServerless本体によって管理されていなさそうです。（上記回答を書く際に軽く見た範囲では確認できず）